# Can't send POST values outside of Wordpress from Contact Form 7 Form

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

my objective is to submit values via POST of a contact form 7 to a redirected outside php page and echo those values.

The issue is when the page is redirected after the submission, the values seem to be lost unless i remove the JS and change the action Url of the form ending up removing all the contact form 7 features which i require (validation, email sent, etc..).

I tried multiple plugins such as contact form 7 to API and it only works via GET method which i don't want. I tried to get the posted values and transforming them into session but it's not working because i'm probably doing something wrong.

Here's the form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OANRQ.jpg)

Here's the result that is supose to be shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMkjQ.jpg)

**UPDATE:**

Ok so i posted the function to fetch the posted data and the var_dump missing on the result php file.

Here's the fucntions.php

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'send_post_values' );


  if ($form_id == 7627) {

    $user      = $cf7->posted_data["user"];
    $email = $cf7->posted_data["email"];
    $country  = $cf7->posted_data["country"];

    //any code missing??

  }

}
```

Here's the show-values.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
echo "Name: " . $_POST["user"] . "<br>"; 
echo "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";
echo "Country: " . $_POST["country"] . "<br>";
?>
```

And here's the JS i put on the edit page of wordpress for redirection

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = 'https://www.xxxxx.xxx/forms/show-values.php';
}, false );
```

The output is still missing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7lAW.jpg)

Not using any extra plugin besides cf7 at the moment.

Comment: Please attach your code here

Comment: The only code that i have is in the result page:

`<?php
echo "<br><br><br> Method Post: <br>".$_POST."<br><br><br>";
echo "Name: " . $_POST["user"] . "<br>"; 
echo "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";
echo "Country: " . $_POST["country"] . "<br>";
echo "<br><br><br>";
?>`

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, use `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` to print out the $_post. `echo "Name: " . $_POST["user"]` is ok.

Comment: Thank you Mahfuzul, but the array is coming with 0 elements so the post values are not being passed...

Comment: Updated my Ans, Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that when redirecting request on browser side you are basically starting completely new request that will be GET request. Some of the things you can try:

1. Transfer data as GET parameters. Simplest but not what you want.
2. Use Javascript to submit form again after first submit but this time to needed URL.
3. Save data after submit and retrieve it on correct page after redirect. Basically what you tried with session but you said it didn't work. Did you use `session_start()`? Also it only works if both pages are part of same web page. You can also try storing this data in file/database/somewhere else and maybe passing on some sort of id as GET parameter to find that data after redirect.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this instead of redirecting to your code:

```
funtionThatCallsMyHandler() {
    //yourcode
}
```

Put that in functions.php then in the spot you're calling your redirect code instead do:

```
funtionThatCallsMyHandler();
redirect
exit
```

That way it still has the post data in the first place, vs chaining redirects.

Comment: I forgot ot mention, it's the same domain and server. Just an extra folder outside of the wordpress core folders.

Comment: When you say redirected do you mean you're trying to pass post's vars through a WP redirect? ie FORM > Redirect > final destination?

Comment: I'm trying to pass through a plugin that redirects after the submission. That's why i tried the SESSION since i'm sure it doesn't save the POST values.

Comment: There's your issue, GET params (seem to be) maintained when they redirect (just holding current URI data w\e it is), but POST data won't be passed on unless you dink with their code, or write a custom handler for that if it's being submitted via another plugin's form.  That said it should be pretty easy to inject what you want to happen into the other plugins flow with how wp works vs trying to chain redirects

Comment: I apologize, my knowledge on this issue is quite limited and i can't understand what you mean by "dink" with their code or writing a custom handler.
The only objective on that php page outisde of wp, is only showing the values and nothing else via POST or SESSION. What kind of custom handler are you referring to? Sorry again for this dumb questions..

Comment: You can't echo a POST array. Change `""<br><br><br> Method Post: <br>".$_POST."<br><br><br>"` to `""<br><br><br> Method Post: <br>".print_r($_POST, true)."<br><br><br>"`

Comment: when did I say anything about echoing?  I said you could inject your process into the one generating the form's handler...

Comment: So yo be clear you wanna build a form via their app and then have that form go to your handler (do you want it to go through their w\e first or go straight to yours)?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply and the wrong explanation. I didn't want to meant "throught" the plugin but "with" the redirect plugin. I'll rephrase the process:
After submitting the cf7 form i need to send the POST values directly to the php page that i created with only the code that i put in the other commentary. I already put the var_dump($_POST) but it comes with 0 elemnts passed so the problem is not having the post values passing to that .php. Since cf7 stays in the same page after submit, i used a redirect plugin to go to that page. That's it

Comment: What are you using to generate the redirect?  instead of redirecting immediately you can inject your code at that point as a function at the point it's still got the POST vars and redirect after to the processed page... Edited above

Comment: I was using the plugin Contact form 7 redirection but i removed and used the JS https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/ instead so i know it only executes the redirection and no other possible things. The array is still 0 on the result page.
What do you mean by injecting my code as a function? Is it possible to show me an example so i can understand completely what do you mean please?

Comment: Thank you Mason for the example but the code used for the redirection after submit is in JS and not php.  Also, what code do you want me to use on `funtionThatCallsMyHandler()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Contact Form 7 hook for this.

try this:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'do_your_task' );

function do_your_task($cf7) {
  $form_id = $cf7->id();

  // Do some task only for specific form
  if ($form_id == 123) { // 123 => Your Form ID.

    $email      = $cf7->posted_data["your-email"]; // Update "your-email" to the actual field name you have given in the form
    $first_name = $cf7->posted_data["your-firstname"];
    $last_name  = $cf7->posted_data["your-lastname"];


    //pass data to 3'rd party API

  }

}
```

See all the [hooks provided by Contact Form 7](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/hooks/)

**Update:**
As you updated the question. for your case you can try this:
You can send values via query string via url or by creating a session variable.

Add this code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'send_form_data' );

function send_form_data($cf7) {
  $form_id = $cf7->id();

  // Do some task only for specific form
  if ($form_id == 123) { // 123 => Your Form ID.    
    $posted_data_str = http_build_query( array("data" => $cf7->posted_data ) );
    $location =  "https://www.xxxxx.xxx/forms/show-values.php?" . $posted_data_str;
    wp_redirect( $location );
    die();
  }
}
```

now no need to redirect via js

in your `show-values.php` file add the following code.

```
$get_data = $_GET['data'];
if ( !empty($get_data)) {
  var_dump($get_data);

  echo "Name: " . $get_data["your-name"] . "<br>";  // Change "your-name"
}
```

However, another way is by creating a SESSION variable.

Comment: The code fetch the values into vars but how do i echo it on the other side? Do i convert those vars intro $_SESSION and echo the SESSION in the other side?

Answer (score -1):

The other answer here is basically right, it just assumes you know how wordpress works.  There's a file called functions.php that's generally where you want to to add any php code to w\e your doing.  How to interact with it is a two part thing, first you declare a function like normal:

```
function what_I_wanna_do {
    // stuff
}
```

Then you declare a trigger that calls the function:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'what_I_wanna_do' );
```

In that trigger the contact form plugin allows you to hook into it so you can fire something, in this case, before that plugins core functions occur.  Basically that line says, before doing the contact form stuff, run function "what_I_wanna_do".  Put all the stuff you want to happen in what_I_wanna_do, then exit\redirect however you want at the end.  You can declare all these things in functions.php (or make your own plugin so it's easier to drop in and out of the code\update WP).

Comment: I updated the main post for better understanding of what i did.